How to send the caller object as parameter to the callback function
How can i access a member of a class object from its own callback function?
I try to send the caller object as parameter of the callback function and access it from the callback function.
In the following code i get an error: invalid use of void expression on this line test.onEvent(onUpdateEvent(test));
One solution is to define the test object as global and define the onEvent function as void onEvent(const std::function<void()> &callback) and remove parameters from callback functions.
But i would like to know if there is another way. This is an example code:
#include <iostream>

#include <functional>

class Test
{
  public:
    int x;
    void onEvent(const std::function<void(Test)> &callback)
    {
            Test_Callback = callback;
    };

    std::function<void(Test)> Test_Callback;     

    void Update()
    {
        x += 1;
        if (Test_Callback)
        {
            Test_Callback(.......);  <--- What parameter to use? If i use *this, i get the error i mentioned
        }
    }
};

void onUpdateEvent(Test& t)
{
    printf("update %d\r\n", t.x);
}

int main()
{
    Test test;
    test.onEvent(onUpdateEvent(test));

    while (1)
    {
        test.Update();   
    }

    return 0;
}



The result of the callback is void, that's what the error is about. You're calling the "callback" and pass the result as parameter, which is wrong.

*"If i use this, i get the error i mentioned" If you use *this, it fixes this error and simply exposes the next error. Remove (test) from test.onEvent(onUpdateEvent(test)); and make the parameters of onUpdateEvent and std::function consistent (either both by value, or both by reference).

Side note: I'd pretty much expect that std::function<void(Test)> is not what you want, most likely you want to operate the function on the object passed, not a copy of, thus you'd need std::function<void(Test&)> – the actual function uses a reference already, so you get the consistence @HolyBlackCat mentioned already as well.

The problem is that you're using the return value of the function call onUpdateEvent(test) as an argument. This is invalid because onUpdateEvent has void as its return type.

So to solve this, don't use the return value of the call onUpdateEvent(test) as an argument. Instead just pass a pointer to onUpdateEvent as argument as shown below. Also do note the additional changes made which are highlighted in the comments of the code snippet:
class Test
{
  public:
    int x;
    void onEvent(const std::function<void(Test)> &callback)
    {
            Test_Callback = callback;
    };

//---------------------vvvvvvvvvvv------->same type as of onUpdateEvent's parameter
    std::function<void(const Test&)> Test_Callback;     

    void Update()
    {
        x += 1;
        if (Test_Callback)
        {
            Test_Callback(*this); // <--- What parameter to use? If i use *this, i get the error i mentioned
        }
    }
};
//-----------------vvvvv---------->added const here since this doesn't change anything
void onUpdateEvent(const Test& t)
{
    printf("update %d\r\n", t.x);
}

int main()
{
    Test test;
    //------------------------v--> pass pointer to function as argument instead of passing return value as arg
    test.onEvent(onUpdateEvent);

    while (1)
    {
        test.Update();   
    }

    return 0;
}

Working demo

const-ness is certainly correct for onUpdateEvent – and still allows to be assigned to the unchanged std::function object. That one having a const parameter not necessarily, though – other callbacks might change the object (and intentionally be allowed to) – so if correct or not depends on the use case...

Your intention is to call
void onEvent(const std::function<void(Test)> &callback)

with the callback, but your line
test.onEvent(onUpdateEvent(test));

actually calls your callback function and tries to pass the result.
The easiest/most general way to fix this is by using a lambda:
test.onEvent([](Test myTest) { onUpdateEvent(myTest); });

Note: I'm not entirely sure which "test" you want to pass, so I'm assuming you want to use a "test" parameter on the callback function, rather than using the test from onEvent call...

I'd rather assume that the std::function should accept its parameter by reference as well (not doing so being a bug) – and if so, 'easiest' actually would be simply passing the function to: test.onEvent(&onUpdateEvent);...

@Aconcagua yeah, the parameters are bit messed up, but...
As for "easiest" -- this might have a been a more impulsive thing. I often do callbacks with member functions (i.e. std::bind and similar templates), I might want to pass in some other data (the good old void* userdata pointer from back when), or make other minor adjustments -- lambdas cover all these cases. So yes, I have to admit that just passing the function pointer didn't even occur to me, since I don't remember the last time I did this...
